# Python and QGIS Solar Irradiation

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to run the "r.sun.insoltime" which is an algorithm in QGIS software, using Python scripts in Pycharm, but without needing to install the QGIS or GRASS on the local computer. I just want to use the Python codes and libraries related to these algorithms for QGIS. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with QGIS software, but have used the [pvlib python](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to compute solar insolation.